# MySQL 'IN' performance

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization

I have a question about MySQL 'IN' performance. Take a look at this query below:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(items.id) AS total
FROM items
    INNER JOIN treatments ON treatments.id = items.treatments_id 
WHERE items.franchise_id IN (
    4,
    48,
    163,
    328,
    443,
    529,
    563,
    579,
    613,
    764,
    774,
    884,
    942,
    970,
    1092,
    1188 
)
AND items.date BETWEEN '2020-08-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-08-03 23:59:59'
```

It takes about 1.3s to finish. However, if I add a string inside the IN condition, it takes only 100ms and the result is exactly the same. Like this:

```
WHERE items.franchise_id IN (
        4,
        48,
        163,
        328,
        443,
        529,
        563,
        579,
        613,
        764,
        774,
        884,
        942,
        970,
        1092,
        1188,
        "faster"
    )
```

`items.franchise_id` is an INT field, any idea why a string makes so much difference?

Without string
[image]

With String
[image]

Comment: Please share more details, like the execution plan of both queries

Comment: Does it still produce the right resultset?

Comment: Second query is using cache, isn't? Check indexes, explain. 100ms is sooo slow for this query too if you haven't billions entries.

Comment: Yes, the resultset is the same.

Comment: No, no cache. I tried many times, with and without string.

Comment: The items table has about 30mi entries and the treatments about 5mi.

Comment: Then please edit your question to contain the execution plan of both queries

Comment: I added the query plan

Comment: Please share more details, like the table structure, such that others can inspect why which key was chosen

Comment: Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info) then [edit] your question to show a few more details.  And, fun fact to know and tell: When you use strings in an integer context, MySQL silently coerces them to an integer pulled from leading digits in the string.  So `'faster'` means `0` and `'123faster'` means `123`.

Comment: Thanks, O. Jones.

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We need row counts because that can affect query planning. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well.

Comment: What is the datatype for `franchise_id`?